absolutely positioned element stretches viewport when scaled
I have an absolutely positioned SVG inside a parent of <main>. When I animate the SVG's transform property using keyframes and scale it up in the Y-direction, it expands but also stretches the viewport. It seems that it's not actually removed from the document flow like it should be, but is rather rendered as a child of the body.
Effective markup:
<main class="container">
  <svg class="img">
    <!-- ... -->
  </svg>
</main>

Effective styles on the parent:
.container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

Effective styles on the SVG:
.img {
  width: 260%;
  rotate: 180deg;
  height: 75px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
}

Note that I do have relative position set on the parent so that the absolute positioning of the child SVG will take effect.
Full markup:
<main className='relative bg-neutral-950 text-white overflow-x-hidden !max-h-screen h-screen w-screen'>
    <div className='h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-12 p-24'>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <svg
        preserveAspectRatio='none'
        viewBox='0 0 1200 120'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        style={{
            fill: '#ffffff',
            width: '260%',
            rotate: '180deg',
            height: 75,
            transformOrigin: 'bottom',
            zIndex: 1_000
        }}
        className='absolute bottom-0 animate-grow-snow'
    >
        <path d='M321.39 56.44c58-10.79 114.16-30.13 172-41.86 82.39-16.72 168.19-17.73 250.45-.39C823.78 31 906.67 72 985.66 92.83c70.05 18.48 146.53 26.09 214.34 3V0H0v27.35a600.21 600.21 0 00321.39 29.09z' />
    </svg>
    <Snowfall />
</main>

CSS keyframes from my Tailwind configuration:
'grow-snow': {
    '0%': { transform: 'scale(-10, 1)' },
    '100%': { transform: 'scale(-1, 3)' }
}
// ...
'grow-snow': 'grow-snow 30s linear both 10s'

Screenshots after the animation completes:


As you can see, the viewport can be scrolled, but there is nothing else rendered. Upon hovering in DevTools, the SVG element is below the main, when it should be over it.
The intended effect is that the bottom edge of the SVG stays anchored to the bottom edge of the main, which means the document should be the exact same height as the viewport for now and thus should not be scrollable.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

@keyframes grow-snow {
  from {
    transform: scale(-10, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(-1, 2);
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.flexbox {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3rem;
  padding: 6rem;
}

.svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: grow-snow 10s linear both 5s;
  width: 260%;
  rotate: 180deg;
  height: 75;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  z-index: 1000;
}
<main class="container">
  <div class="flexbox">
    <h1>foobar</h1>
  </div>
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg">
                <path
                    d="M321.39 56.44c58-10.79 114.16-30.13 172-41.86 82.39-16.72 168.19-17.73 250.45-.39C823.78 31 906.67 72 985.66 92.83c70.05 18.48 146.53 26.09 214.34 3V0H0v27.35a600.21 600.21 0 00321.39 29.09z"
                />
            </svg>
  <Snowfall />
</main>




I'm pretty sure it's removed from the flow and doesn't actually stretch its parent element. Rather, it stretches the viewport (assuming a mobile device?), and your .container follows the viewport's height. Why did you set only overflow-x: hidden and not the same for overflow-y?

@Bergi sorry, I misspoke; edited it to fix.
and overflow hiding is set horizontally to keep the SVG from flowing off the page, but there is no such necessity along the vertical axis

Please edit the code in your post to include the SVG code ... or at least enough SVG code for us to be able to replicate the problem ... to see what you are seeing. It would also be helpful to include some screenshots which illustrate the problem.

@BrettDonald I just added screenshots and code. Note that I am using React, and more importantly, Tailwind, so you might need to search the docs a bit. I took the liberty of adding the styles I felt were important to the top of the post (see "effective styles").

I think to solve this one we're going to need to have a runnable example. To build it you will need to use the generated code available from the source view in your browser, rather than your React source code.

"the SVG element is below the main, when it should be over it." - could that be caused by the rotate: 180deg; with transform-origin: bottom;? Try to rotate it around its center instead

@BrettDonald copied over a minimal example, the problem still persists
